# Unhandled exception at 0x0FC9E559 (ucrtbased.dll) in MyString.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000

Tags: c++, heap-memory

I have a problem in my string class: "Unhandled exception in strcpy function". I do not have much experience in pointers. Please give me your recommendation.
Thank you in advance !

IDE used: Visual Studio 2017

> Unhandled exception at 0x0FC9E559 (ucrtbased.dll) in MyString.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

***MyString.cpp:***

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#include "MyString.h"
#include "cstring"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

MyString::MyString()
{
    length = 0;
    content = NULL;
}

MyString::MyString(int length, const char* content) 
{
    this->length = length;
    this->content = new char[this->length + 1];
    strcpy(this->content, content);
}

MyString::MyString(const char* content)
{
    length = strlen(content);
    this->content = new char[length + 1];
    strcpy(this->content, content);
}

void MyString::setLength(int length) 
{
    this->length = length;
}

const int MyString::getLength() 
{
    return length;
}

void MyString::setContent(char* content) 
{
    strcpy(this->content, content); // Unhandled exception !!!
}

const char* MyString::getContent() 
{
    return content;
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const MyString& string)
{

        out << "Content:\n" << string.content << "\n";
        out << "Length:\n" << string.length << "\n";

    return out;
}

const MyString operator+(MyString& string1, MyString& string2)
{
    MyString concatString;
    concatString.setLength(string1.length + string2.length);
    strcat(string1.content, string2.content);
    concatString.setContent(string1.content);

    return concatString;
}

MyString::~MyString()
{
    delete[] content;
}
```

***MyString.h:***

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyString
{
private:
    int length;
    char* content;

public:

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const MyString& anotherString);

    MyString(); // Constructor fara parametrii
    MyString(int, const char*); // Constructor cu 2 parametrii
    MyString(const char*); // Constructor cu 1 parametru

    friend const MyString operator+(MyString&, MyString&);

    // setters and getters
    void setLength(int);
    const int getLength();
    void setContent(char*);
    const char* getContent();

    // destructor
    ~MyString();
};
```

***Main.cpp:***

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyString.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {

    MyString string1("---");
    MyString string2("..");

    cout << (string1 + string2);


    system("pause");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You don't allocate memory for the `content` of `concatString`

Comment: it still doesn't work

Comment: @Cosmin Provide a [mcve] reproducing your problem please. Also show us your efforts to step through your code line by line with the debugger and exactly identify where the exeception was thrown. Check all the variable values at the stage before calling that statement and explain what your doubts about that exception are.

Comment: Run it in Debugger (F5). It will stop exactly where you're accessing a null pointer (inside operator+).

Comment: @Cosmin you have problems in `operator+` and `setLength` and `setContent`, I put an answer correcting these problems more other remarks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
const MyString operator+(MyString& string1, MyString& string2)
{
    MyString concatString;
    concatString.setLength(string1.length + string2.length);
    strcat(string1.content, string2.content);
    concatString.setContent(string1.content);

    return concatString;
}
```

*concatString* is created empty, and *setLength* only set the length without (re)allocated *content*, so you *strcpy* a null pointer in *setContent*

you also need to copy and concat in *concatString*, not in *string1*

So for instance :

```
void MyString::setLength(int length) 
{
    if (length > this->length) {
      char * b = new char[length + 1];

      if (this->content != NULL) {
        strcpy(b, this->content);
        delete [] this->content;
      }
      this->content = b;
    }
    this->length = length;
}

const MyString operator+(const MyString& string1, const MyString& string2)
{
    MyString concatString;
    concatString.setLength(string1.length + string2.length);
    strcpy(concatString.content, string1.content);
    strcat(concatString.content, string2.content);

    return concatString;
}
```

*setContent* cannot just do a *strcpy*, better to do for instance

```
void MyString::setContent(char* content) 
{
  if (content == NULL) {
    if (this->content != NULL) 
      delete [] this->content;
    this->content = NULL;
    this->length = 0;
  }
  else {
    setLength(strlen(content));
    strcpy(this->content, content);
  }
}
```

After these two changes, compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra -g MyString.cpp Main.cpp 
In file included from MyString.cpp:2:0:
MyString.h:22:25: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
     const int getLength();
                         ^
MyString.cpp:41:31: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
 const int MyString::getLength()
                               ^
In file included from Main.cpp:2:0:
MyString.h:22:25: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
     const int getLength();

pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Content:
---..
Length:
5
sh: 1: pause: not found
```

and under *valgrind*

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==6134== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6134== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6134== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6134== Command: ./a.out
==6134== 
Content:
---..
Length:
5
sh: 1: pause: not found
==6134== 
==6134== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6134==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6134==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 21,261 bytes allocated
==6134== 
==6134== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==6134== 
==6134== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6134== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

To not have the warning during the compilation do not return *const int* but just *int*

It is better to have *length* to be a `size_t`  rather than a *int*

*getLength* and *getContent* can be *const* (`int getLength() const` and `const char* getContent() const`)

---

As Christophe says in a remark `operator+` returns a copy of the string and  you do not define the copy constructor, nor the `operator=`. When a class contains pointers it is needed to define them, and with recent C++ also the *move*

Comment: Hi Bruno ! well done! However I wonder why there are no memory issues, since operator+ returns a MyString and the default copy constructor would cause a shallow copy and a double delete. Is because of copy elision ? wouldn’t a copy constructor be required to make this work for sure ?

Comment: @Christophe yes you are right. The `operator=` is also missing. It is strange _valgrind_ said nothing about the double delete. I edit my answer to add your remarks

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with this code.

First, you need to implement the [rule of 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)),  so also providing a copy constructor and an assignment operator.

Then `setLength()` adjust the maximum length of your string, but it fails to allocate anything,  so that you may create a buffer overflow, or in case the default constructor was used an UB because of the nullptr.  This is what happens in your `operator+()`.

Once you have implemented the rule of 3, a quick fix for operator+ could be:

```
const MyString operator+(MyString& string1, MyString& string2)
{
    MyString concatString(string1.length + string2.length, string1.content);
    strcat(concatString.content, string2.content);

    return concatString;   // but this requires copy constructor to work
}
```

You for your length-based constructor, you assule that length is larger than the string that you want to copy.  So either you assert this, or you use `strncpy()`